# Why cannot I see apps cards in camera mode

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

I have successfully installed all the extension&support apps from sony and 2-3 example apps for example HelloSensor. I can select the apps to get cards from and see HelloSensor output.

But whenever I press the camera button and go to VR mode in emulator the device begin to show the camera app and not the selected HelloSensor app cards.

Does any one have any comments on that?

Regards

Comment: Maybe because it's a just a preview version and still full of bugs. It was only released two days ago after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, what do you want to achieve. Pressing camera button starts the built-in camera application. So the behaviour you are describing is expected.

Maybe it is confusing for you, that the camera is not showing on the background, until the camera API is in use. That doesn't mean, that the glasses are not in AR mode. They are AR always, as the eyewear display is transparent.

Comment: Ok I understand that. Thx for the answer. As you say I was expecting to see the camera in all cases. Like a simulation for the transparency of the eyeglasses.